# Want to display HTML output of a .html file stored on onedrive in my android app

Tags: android, html

I am developing a app using android studio and want to display a HTML file saved on a external drive(eg.Onedrive) but it opens the file and shows the contents not the HTML output. so is there any way to do this? i am using webview.loadUrl and giving the onedrive link of the file

Comment: If i use the assets folder to display local HTML files it works bt not for the files stored on any external storage. It shows the contents of .html file and not the output of .html file.

Comment: I'm voting to migrate the question to [so], since it's a development question and off topic here.